# Sequential ordering from a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table of products that are associated to a retailer_id in a MySQL database and I would like to do a search on that table by a keyword on the title field but I would like to return the items in a sequential pattern using the retailer_id.

Pulling my hair out with this one but basically what I want to do is the following:-

| title | retailer_id |
| --- | --- |
| red dress | 1 |
| red dress | 1 |
| red dress | 2 |
| red dress | 3 |
| red dress | 5 |
| red dress | 4 |
| red dress | 4 |
| red dress | 3 |
| red dress | 3 |
| red dress | 4 |

I want to search for red dress which will show all results but then I want to sequentially order by retailer_id so the final output would be:-

| title | retailer_id |
| --- | --- |
| red dress | 1 |
| red dress | 2 |
| red dress | 3 |
| red dress | 4 |
| red dress | 5 |
| red dress | 1 |
| red dress | 3 |
| red dress | 4 |
| red dress | 3 |
| red dress | 4 |

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Where is the "sequential" part of *sequential*?

Comment: Sorry? Not getting you @Stu

Comment: What is the logic behind the ordering of retailer_id?

Comment: Basically I’m trying to not give any retailer extra “weight” to another so I am trying to order the results on a one row per retailer basis until they run out. Hope that explains it. Head has been stuck trying things for far too long.

Comment: Because the retailer ids are 1-5 with 5 being the maximum. There are a lot more in the full dataset  but I included a smaller dataset here for ease.

Comment: I think I uderstand, you need to rank the retailers using *row_number* - hopefully you're using MySql 8?

Comment: Yes I am using MySQL 8 :) do you have an example of what you mean by chance? Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *row_number* you can rank each retailer_Id and order like so:

```
select retailer_id 
from (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by retailer_id order by retailer_id) rnk
    from t
)t
order by rnk, retailer_id;
```

Comment: Just seen that the server that this one is on is MariaDB so I’ll have to upgrade the server and try this. Apologies, thank you for your response.

Comment: @WillRoberts works fine [on MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=e5f53da31a5edc593aa5b7fbc825755d)

Comment: That works beautifully @Stu, thank you.